# Ключевое слово synchronized в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Выполняю пример из книги немного мною модифицированный:

```
public class SynchroRun {
    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (s) {
                    while (SynchroRun.counter.get() < 3) {
                        s.append("A");
                        counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        Thread.sleep(1);

        while (SynchroRun.counter.get() < 6) {
            s.append("B");
            counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
        }
        
        System.out.println("результат: " + s);
    }
}
```

Вывод будет таким:
"результат: ABBBBB".

Я не понимаю, почему блок кода из-за слова synchronized не выполняется целиком, я жду "результат: AAABBB".

Зато, если добавить слово synchronized к другому блоку кода, все выполняется так, как я и ожидала:

```
public class SynchroRun {
    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (s) {
                    while (SynchroRun.counter.get() < 3) {
                        s.append("A");
                        counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        Thread.sleep(1);
        
        synchronized (s) {
            while (SynchroRun.counter.get() < 6) {
                s.append("B");
                counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("результат: " + s);
    }
}
```

Вывод: "результат: AAABBB".

Объясните, пожалуйста, что произошло?

Comment: `counter.set(counter.get() + 1)` -- не атомарно; между `get` и `set` может что-то вклиниться; у `AtomicInteger` есть `incrementAndGet()`;

Comment: это да, спасибо, только в данной задаче на результаты это никак не повлияло

Comment: Не повлияло, т. к. вероятность маленькая; в другом случае будет больше; плюс вероятности (не глюканья) имеют свойство перемножаться; так что, лучше себе сразу алерт в голове поставить; а то вылавливать нечастый баг в многопоточном приложении -- то еще развлечение.

Answer (score 3):

Синхронизация работает, как блокировка. Первый блок кода заблокировал доступ к объекту `s` для любого другого кода, которых хочет его изменить или прочитать, и который так же с ним синхронизирован.
В то же время на код, который не синхронизирован с этим объектом, никакие ограничения не накладываются, и он может делать с ним, что хочет.

При желании вы можете заменить структуру вашей программы на аналогичную, используя `ReentrantLock`.

```java
public class SynchroRun {
    
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            while (counter.get() < 3) {
                s.append('A');
                counter.incrementAndGet();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            lock.unlock();    
        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(1);

        lock.lock();
        while (counter.get() < 6) {
            s.append('B');
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
        lock.unlock();

        System.out.println("результат: " + s);
    }
}
```

Здесь всё очень наглядно. Точно так же работает и `synchronized`.